# How to get the correct selected value in Select HTML from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I get users from mysql query. I show this users into table and add a  HTML into php file to all users to change a value:

```
 ...
 do {
    echo "<td > <a>".$row["username"]."</a> </td> \n";  
    echo "<td > <a>".$row["name"]."</a> </td> \n";
    echo "<td > <select id='sel'> <option value='admin'>Admin</option> <option value='user'>User</option> </select> </td> \n";   
 } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
        echo "</tbody></table> \n";
 ...
```

How can I get the option selected??

I'm trying  get this in javascript but always get the same first value, independet value selected.

```
function myFunction() {
   var e = document.getElementById("sel");
   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `$('#sel option:selected').val()` and get back on me

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery `.change` function.

Fiddle :- https://jsfiddle.net/a2abaL44/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#sel").change(function(){
    var selectVal = $(this).val();
})
</script>
```

https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

Because your loop will be executed multiple times (once for each user in the database), you will have many `<select>` elements with the same ID. You cannot have the same ID given to many different elements, and this is why your JavaScript is only returning the value of the first `<select>`.

If you tell me what you are needing the selected value for, I can update the answer further.

Comment: yes this is returning only the first. I want show the options: admin or user in a <select> for the users like my code show. And show a button  next to each <select> for execute javascript to get value of the <select> near to send this post php. I hope I've explained myself well

Comment: So you are wanting to have a button next to each of the <select> elements (1 button for 1 select)?

Comment: Are you able to explain the scenario a bit more or show the rest of the code for the table? It would be very helpful to see what you would like the finished table to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, Change your select to `<select id="sel" onchange="myFunction();">`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
   var e = document.getElementById("sel");
   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   alert(strUser);
}
</script>
```